# Is there an intuitive reason for why the reciprocal lattice of FCC is BCC and vice versa?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

This can be proved using formulae for generating reciprocal lattice vectors from direct lattice vectors. But does this result have more to it than meets the eye?

Comment: And the reciprocal lattice of hcp is another hcp lattice! What kind of deeper meaning are you expecting?  High symmetry lattices have high symmetry reciprocal lattices.  And everyone ignore poor trigonal over there in the corner all alone...

Comment: Try to find a plane in which 5 spheres are located in both structures (square with one in the middle). Now try to rotate one of the two such that both planes allign ans try to find which spheres outside of the plane will allign (maybe imagine a few structures stacked on top of each other). You should see that they will all lineup with the other structure, but this will require some spatial visualisation.